# Factoring a natural transformation through a functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, 2-categories

This seems fairly similar to density. Suppose I have three categories $A,B,C$, and a functor $L: B \to C$ so that every natural transformation $f: L.F \Rightarrow L.G$, for a parallel pair $F,G: A \to B$ belonging to some class of functors $\mathcal{F}$, factors as a natural transformation $g:F \Rightarrow G$ so that $L.g = f$. This feels like a thing that would come up in 2-category theory, but I'm struggling to find a good reference.

Here is a [diagram](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNixbMSwwLCJBIl0sWzMsMCwiQiJdLFs0LDAsIkMiXSxbMCwyLCI9Il0sWzEsMiwiQSJdLFszLDIsIkMiXSxbMCwxLCJGIiwxLHsiY3VydmUiOi0zfV0sWzAsMSwiRyIsMSx7ImN1cnZlIjozfV0sWzEsMiwiTCIsMV0sWzQsNSwiTC5GIiwxLHsiY3VydmUiOi0zfV0sWzQsNSwiTC5HIiwxLHsiY3VydmUiOjN9XSxbNiw3LCJmIiwxLHsic2hvcnRlbiI6eyJzb3VyY2UiOjIwLCJ0YXJnZXQiOjIwfX1dLFs5LDEwLCJnIiwxLHsic2hvcnRlbiI6eyJzb3VyY2UiOjIwLCJ0YXJnZXQiOjIwfX1dXQ==&macro_url=https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fbenjamin-macadam%2Ftex-preamble%2Fmain%2Fpreamble.sty) using the quiver app

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is? It sounds like you're asking for $L$ to be fully faithful, so that postcomposition by $L$ induces an isomorphism between 2-cells $L \circ F \Rightarrow L \circ G$ and 2-cells $F \Rightarrow G$.

Comment: @varkor full faithfulness would mean a unique factorisation

Comment: Yeah it’s a bit weaker than that - I have a 2-monad and three strict algebras of it. The morphism $B$ to $C$ acts like an inserter for every parallel pair of strict algebra homomorphisms. My example certainly isn’t a fully faithful functor - it’s actually a reflector.

Comment: I think it is a particular case of an inserter, but without uniqueness of the 1-cell; the non-uniqueness instead suggests some sort of (weak) orthogonality condition.

Comment: If you don't want uniqueness of the factorisation, you can ask for $L$ just to be full. If it arises via a universal property (without uniqueness), then this is suggestive of a [weak (2-)limit](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+limit) as @fosco points out.